# Haskell read variable name

Tags: parsing, haskell

I need to write a code that parses some language. I got stuck on parsing variable name - it can be anything that is at least 1 char long, starts with lowercase letter and can contain underscore '_' character. I think I made a good start with following code:

```
identToken :: Parser String
identToken = do 
                       c <- letter
                       cs <- letdigs
                       return (c:cs)
             where letter = satisfy isLetter
                   letdigs = munch isLetter +++ munch isDigit +++ munch underscore
                   num = satisfy isDigit
                   underscore = \x -> x == '_'
                   lowerCase = \x -> x `elem` ['a'..'z'] -- how to add this function to current code?

ident :: Parser Ident
ident = do 
          _ <- skipSpaces
          s <- identToken
          skipSpaces; return $ s

idents :: Parser Command
idents = do 
          skipSpaces; ids <- many1 ident
          ...
```

This function however gives me a weird results. If I call my test function

```
test_parseIdents :: String -> Either Error [Ident]
test_parseIdents p = 
  case readP_to_S prog p of
    [(j, "")] -> Right j
    [] -> Left InvalidParse
    multipleRes -> Left (AmbiguousIdents multipleRes)
  where
    prog :: Parser [Ident]
    prog = do
      result <- many ident
      eof
      return result
```

like this:

```
test_parseIdents  "test"
```

I get this:

```
Left (AmbiguousIdents [(["test"],""),(["t","est"],""),(["t","e","st"],""),
    (["t","e","st"],""),(["t","est"],""),(["t","e","st"],""),(["t","e","st"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),
    (["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],""),(["t","e","s","t"],"")])
```

Note that `Parser` is just synonym for `ReadP a`.

I also want to encode in the parser that variable names should start with a lowercase character.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is with your use of the `+++` operator. The following code works for me:

```
import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

type Parser a = ReadP a
type Ident = String

identToken :: Parser String
identToken = do c <- satisfy lowerCase
                cs <- letdigs
                return (c:cs)
  where lowerCase = \x -> x `elem` ['a'..'z']
        underscore = \x -> x == '_'
        letdigs = munch (\c -> isLetter c || isDigit c || underscore c)

ident :: Parser Ident
ident = do _ <- skipSpaces
           s <- identToken
           skipSpaces
           return s

test_parseIdents :: String -> Either String [Ident]
test_parseIdents p = case readP_to_S prog p of
    [(j, "")]   -> Right j
    []          -> Left "Invalid parse"
    multipleRes -> Left ("Ambiguous idents: " ++ show multipleRes)
  where prog :: Parser [Ident]
        prog = do result <- many ident
                  eof
                  return result

main = print $ test_parseIdents "test_1349_zefz"
```

So what went wrong:

- `+++` imposes an order on its arguments, and allows for multiple alternatives to succeed ([symmetric choice](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.6/base-4.8.1.0/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html)). `<++` is left-biased so only the left-most option succeeds -> this would remove the ambiguity in the parse, but still leaves the next problem.
- Your parser was looking for letters *first*, *then* digits, and *finally* underscores. Digits after underscores failed, for example. The parser had to be modified to `munch` characters that were *either* letters, digits or underscores.

I also removed some functions that were unused and made an educated guess for the definition of your datatypes.